# If else in Gradle scripts

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle.properties

I have this really strange behavior in Gradle and I cannot find a way out of it. In my `gradle.properties` file, I am using this checking condition:

```
//gradle.properties

if ( "${System.Property['DATABASE_DIR']}".compareTo('swdb') == 0 ) {
    PROJECT_DATABASE_PATH=../database/swdb/include
    }   
else {
    PROJECT_DATABASE_PATH=../database/include/
}
```

I created a new task called `printProperties` and it looks like this.

```
//build.gradle
task printProperties {
    println "${System.properties['DATABASE_DIR']}".compareTo('swdb') == 0
    println PROJECT_DATABASE_PATH
}
```

I get the following output when I run the `printProperties` task.

> $gradle printProperties -DDATABASE_DIR=swdb
>
> true
>
> ../database/include/
>
> :printProperties UP-TO-DATE
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 1.07 secs

It is really strange that the task prints true but the `gradle.properties` file does not evaluate the same condition correctly. Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: Are you sure you can use code in `gradle.properties`? I thought it is really just a plain old properties file.

Comment: I am really not sure. Its not clearly documented as to if I could use some code in there or not. If I should not be using code there, then I will create a new question to meet my difficulty. I need to be able to choose the location of headers needed to compile the code depending on a command line defined system property for a native Gradle model.

Comment: `gradle.properties` is a properties file with `key=value` pairs. You can't put groovy code in there

Answer (score 5):

Your code shall take place in a `init.gradle` script.

You can find documentation here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html

`gradle.properties` file is only for key=value pairs